# images responsive to height

Tags: css, wordpress, image, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive WP theme for a gallery of images. Everything works fine when responding to width. I tried to set a screen size that responds to height as my images were getting cut off on small laptops at 1200 x 800. I've tried a few different things and they all do what I want them to do, but they change the style for every screen size, and not just 1200 x 800.

```
@viewport {
    width: device-width;
}

/** 
Small Desktop < 1200px */

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

    }

img {
    height: 75%;
    max-height: 650px; 
    width: 75%;
}
```

I also tried `@media screen and (max-height: 700px)` but the results were identical.

Comment: Did you try setting the width of the image inside the @media? The @media will do nothing at all unless you set CSS selectors inside it to something.

Comment: Did u try adding it inside @media screen and (width: 1200px) and (height: 800px) {}

Comment: You may also want to try to set the view port using HTML. I have never actually used the CSS view port. Try this in your header:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

Comment: @WilliamCallahan That seems to do it. For the ones that respond to width, they've never had to be inside. Weird. If you want, write that up as an answer and I'll give you the credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but your code is simply doing nothing since there are no CSS selectors inside the @media selector. In addition, make sure that you set the meta view port in the header of your HTML. Try to fiddle around with this code:

```
<html>
      <head>
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
           <style>
                img {
                    height: 75%;
                    max-height: 650px; 
                    width: 75%;
                }
                @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
                     /*This is just an example*/
                     img {
                         height: 100px;
                         max-height: 650px; 
                         width: 100px;
                     }
                }
           </style>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
</html>
```

Also, it is important to note that the order of the `@media` selector does matter. You can have multiple `@media`'s for multiple sizes. Just make sure that if you use the `max-width`, you have the smaller widths in ascending order (from a smaller width to a larger width).